# How to highlight nonmatching values based on certain column values in VBA

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

How would I go about implementing a macro or conditional formatting rule that would compare two separate sheets based on their values in a column?

Basically, what I need to do is search each sheet for the matching values (e.g. cell `A10` would be "project 10" and on the other sheet it might be cell `A6` as "project 10").

Then it would look at a separate column, and match the dates there (i.e, cell `A10` would have date "11/12/15" and cell `A6` on the other sheet would have a date of "11/11/15") highlighting the cell if it is different than the date on the first sheet.

The tricky thing here is that the projects are in a different order on each sheet (as explained above). I have attempted several code suggestions but have not gotten anywhere yet.

Comment: What version of Excel? You need 2010 or higher to reference a value on another worksheet in a CF rule (or work-around with named ranges). Sample data together with expected results would go a long way to clarify matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's solve using conditional formatting.

As you may be aware, conditional formatting works by setting up a rule which governs the cell you apply it to. If that rule produces TRUE, then the rule is applied (diff colour, etc). So the goal here is to make a formula which results in TRUE when all of your conditions are met. There are two conditions we care about here. First, does the item in column A on sheet1 exist in column A on sheet2?

```
=not(iserror(match($A1,sheet2!$A:$A,0)))
```

First, it uses the MATCH function to check if A1 (with an absolute reference on the column, so that as you apply the rule to columns A & B it will not look at column B at all) exists on sheet2 columnA. If it does exist, it will spit out the row number that it appears at. If it does not exist, it will create an error. So that is wrapped in ISERROR which says "if this argument returns an error, spit out TRUE". But, we want it to return TRUE when there is *no* error. So, we wrap that in NOT, which reverses TRUE to FALSE, and vice versa.

Now what you actually care about is, if A1 exists in sheet2, then does that row in column B on sheet2 match the value in B1 on sheet1?

So we find the value in column B, where there is a match in column A, by using the index function, like so:

```
=Index(sheet2!$B:$B,match($A1,sheet2!$A:$A,0))
```

This gives that value from column B in sheet 2. So, check: does that value equal the value in B1, sheet1? [We actually check to see if that value is DIFFERENT than B1, so we use "<>" instead of "=".

```
=Index(sheet2!$B:$B,match($A1,sheet2!$A:$A,0))<>$B1
```

Now we just need to replace an error (if Match returns no match) with "".

```
=Iferror(Index(sheet2!$B:$B,match($A1,sheet2!$A:$A,0)),"")<>$B1
```

And that's it. If there's a match in sheet2 columnA [using the MATCH function] it gives you the date from column B [using the INDEX] function. If there's no match, it returns "" [using the IFERROR function]. And then if that value does NOT equal B1, then it results in TRUE, which triggers your conditional formatting.